# Did Itachi Uchiha want to be Hokage when he was young?

Tags: naruto

**Did Itachi Uchiha want to be Hokage when he was young?**

---

My research:

- Hiruzen said that Itachi reasoned like a Hokage at a very young age.

[image]

- [Itachi wanted a **Hokage from Uchiha Clan**.](http://www.saiyanisland.com/2015/12/naruto-shippuden-itachi-uchiha-anime-confirmed/)

> *Itachi Uchiha, age four. After seeing what occurs on the battlefield up close, he makes a certain decision. ***He decided that he would change the world. The dream that Itachi aimed for. His dream: A Hokage from the Uchiha clan, and a future where those he loved could live in peace***. His time in the ninja academy, his meeting with Shisui, becoming a Genin, Chunin, and finally a member of the Anbu… Itachi ran straight down a path of glory, not knowing that a cruel darkness was spreading…This is the story of the glory, frustration, and determination of the ninja called a genius.*

- [Itachi wanted to be the strongest shinobi in the village.](http://uchihasavior.tumblr.com/post/129601792131/itachi-shinden-chapter-1-section-1-translation)
- Itachi developed his version of the definition of Hokage.

[image]
 - [He wanted to change the ways of the world.](http://uchihasavior.tumblr.com/post/129601792131/itachi-shinden-chapter-1-section-1-translation)

Comment: Just because he reasoned like a Hokage doesn't mean he wanted to become one. +1, it's a good question.

Comment: Itachi being a pacifist may have been detrimental to someone having the duties of a kage.

Answer (score 2):

Itachi may have reasoned like a hokage, but he didn't actually want to be Hokage... He would have made an awesome hokage though. Itachi was very intelligent for his age and has the basic ethic to become hokage. I agree with Hirizun on this one. He had the intelligence, logic, curiosity and the will and heart to become hokage.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was Itachi's dream to become hogake. It states so in the book "Itachi's story". Itachi's story is canon to the show and is pretty much Itachi's point of view. So yeah, Itachi did want to become hokage.

Answer (score 0):

Itachi was a pacifist and went through great lengths trying to achieve peace, and was an extraordinary shinobi, however, I don't believe it was ever a goal of his to become hokage, nor do I recall it ever being mentioned. But if you would like to discover more about Itachi and his intentions and motives, fandom is a very informative website you can go to to find out more about the rogue ninja; http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Uchiha

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Alexis Orcutt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/53862/19307), it is stated in the light novel series *Itachi's Story* that Itachi wanted to become Hokage. I have to add a caveat here, however. Becoming Hokage was actually not Itachi's dream. Instead, becoming Hokage was merely a stepping stone to his true dream: ridding the world of all war. At the ninja academy, when everyone's sharing their dreams, it is this second dream that Itachi shares with everyone, and it's then that he realizes how childish all his classmates are. Itachi's maturity and his having a desire to end all war is linked to his father bringing him to the remains of a battlefield when he was four, and Itachi seeing the horrible carnage for himself.

So the answer to the question: Yes, Itachi did want to become Hokage when he was young.